# Bullet not shooting enemy center in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can you please help me to create correctly shoot of bullet to enemy center with my method ?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") && !_shooting)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Shoot());
        _shooting = true;
    }
}

private IEnumerator Shoot()
{
    int random = Random.Range(1, Camera.main.transform.childCount);
    int rnd = Random.Range(0, transform.childCount);
    Instantiate(Bullet, transform.parent);
    target = Camera.main.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position;

    var rb = transform.parent.GetChild(transform.parent.childCount - 1).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.transform.position = positions[rnd];

    transform.GetChild(rnd).GetComponent<Transform>().localScale = new Vector2(1.2f, 1.2f);
    StartCoroutine(ReturnDotSize(rnd));
    while (Vector2.Distance(rb.transform.position, target) > 0.1f)
    {
        rb.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(rb.transform.position, target, shootSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(ReloadTime); 
    _shooting = false;
}
```

Now bullet shoot only one time. I was try to write break instead of yield return null, but in this time bullet not shoot to center of enemy.In addition, I tried to write "_shooting = false" over "yield return null" and in this case the bullet clearly goes to the center of the enemy, but the "ReloadTime" delay does not work. Now I need the bullet to accurately go to the center of the enemy and work correctly "ReloadTime".

Comment: You might want to cache the results of calling `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` or at least not call it 60 times a second.  A **quick** minor win is to change your `if` statement to `if (!_shooting && GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy"))`

Comment: statement if work correctly

Answer (score 0):

For customiztion sake and performance reasons, you should create a script Enemey.cs attached to your Enemey GameObject that has a public transform field named "BulletTarget". This Bullet Target Transform is a child element of your Enemey game object and you can then freely place it where you see the center of your enemy object. Perfomance wise you cen then use FindObjectsOfType which is better and less fragile then by name.